# Finding the angle of object?

Tags: blender

I'm struggling to find the angle of some objects.
The screenshot below shows an armature with its X, Y, Z angles set to zero.  But it's clearly inclined, because it was rotated before, then had its rotations applied with "CTRL+A" --> "Rotation" menu.  Is there any way we can find its angle (Maybe just its edge angles)?

Also, the rectangular bar in the screenshot also has its X, Y, Z angles set to ZERO.  Again, it's clearly inclined, because it was rotated in edit mode, not in object mode.  I'd really appreciate your help to find their angles.  Thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV4bu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAid4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the measure tool to measure angles

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/toolbar/measure.html

Answer (score 0):

You could activate the built in Add On Curve:Extra Objects.
`https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/addons/add_curve/index.html`
With shift A -> Curve -> Curve Profiles -> Arc you create an Arc which could be used for measuring angles in 3D. After creating the arc you could activate Arc type 2 and Arc Option 3D. Choose a vertice of the object you want to measure for the location of the arc and adjust Start and end angle.